# Как реализовать соединение между js в браузере и C#-приложением?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Пробовал через WebSocket, но к удаленному серверу ни в какую не цепляется, прочитал на харбе, что провайдеры порой вырезают заголовки соединения. Какие еще есть способы?

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите? И что именно подразумеваете под "соединением между js и C#"?

Comment: юзер жмет кнопку, данные шлются на отдельное c#-приложение, не связанное с веб-сервером, там обрабатываются и отсылается ответ, браузер принимает и обрабатывает ответ шарпа

Comment: Эмм..вы хотите, что клиентский браузерный код и некое совершенно стороннее приложение общались друг с другом без участия серверной составляющей этого веб-приложения? Не очень понятно, в чем смысл таких танцев с бубном.

Comment: чтобы разгрузить машину с веб-сервером

Comment: Тогда вам понадобится фактически второй сервер, на котором не будет хоститься HTML, но который будет предоставлять нужный интерфейс.

Comment: с websocket есть ещё заморочка ws не везде проходят. но есть и хорошая весть - там проходят wss.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать WebService на asp.net и опубликовать вам где его надо, например example.com
Затем с браузера посылать ajax запросы на эти сервисы. Но чтобы запросы доходили надо в web.config этого сервиса прописать:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="<сайт, который открывает ваш браузер>" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам наверное надо сделать веб сервис для C# приложения, который будет отдавать ему данные. Т.е. схема такая:

Клиент ходит на ваш основной сервер. Жмет кнопку. Сервер формирует данные для c#, складывает их в очередь. Далее проверяет - обработалась ли очередь. Отвечает клиенту или ждёт пока обработается - это уже как вы решите.

C# долбится на веб сервис спрашивая - есть ли для меня данные для обработки. если есть - забирает, обрабатывает, дергает сервис - обработал то-то результат - такой то.

Все счастливы, всё в рамках веб концепции, сервер разгружен.

Врятли Вам в схеме где присутствует "провайдер" можно будет реализовать адекватную схему прямого сокетного взаимодействия и реализовать сокетный сервис. Как минимум должен быть фиксированый айпи и VDS у сервера.

Comment: Сокетный сервис вполне нормально поддерживается в IIS8. В IE сокеты поддерживаются с 10ой версии. Также что сокеты тоже можно попробовать.

Comment: Ну я и говорю, как минимум VDS ка должна быть, на стандартных провайдерских планах врятли есть такая возможность.